# Vuetify: Initial table sorting not working when using slots?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a few data tables where I am using `:sort-by:sync` and `:sort-desc.sync` , and that is working perfectly.  I have this data table below where I am using slots and the data table isn't sorting.  I am getting the warning in my console saying that the property `total` is not referenced in the render.

```
<v-data-table
        id="paid-orders-data-table"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        :hide-default-footer="true"
        :sort-by:sync="total"
        :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
    >
        <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
                    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                    <td>${{ item.total }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </template>
```

---

```
  data() {
        return {
            sortDesc: true,
            headers: [
                {
                    text: 'Customer',
                    sortable: false,
                    value: 'name',
                },
                {
                    text: 'Total',
                    value: 'total'
                },
            ],
            items: []
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `:sort-by.sync="total"` and not `:sort-by:sync="total"` *(take note of the colon before sync)*. Also, the `total` part should be defined as a variable. So Vue tries to find the `total` variable which is non-existent, and throws the error that you are seeing.

```html
<v-data-table ... :sort-by.sync="sortBy">
  <template v-slot:body="{ items }">...</template>
</v-data-table>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    ...
    sortBy: "total",
    headers: [...]
    items: [...]
  };
}
```

Here is a working sample [demo at codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-river-j56jr?file=/src/components/Playground.vue:141-163).

Comment: thanks for the explanation...and thanks for taking the time to give a working code example !

Comment: No worries! If you find this answer useful or any answer here in that regard, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Goodluck to you mate.

Comment: of course, done.  Sorry, was just busy working the last 2 days -- thanks again!